# EntityFrameWork version 6.1.3 installed but it still shows version 6.0.0

Tags: visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I have just started my journey in MVC and EntityFrameWork. I am following a tutorial. When I try to add using option "MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework" the Visual Studio gives me error,

```
"There was an error running selected code generator. 
 Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"
```

I have searched for this error and found different solutions for the same problem. I have tried few and I am now trying to upgrade the Entity FrameWork to version 6.1.3 through Nuget. When I remove the existing package 6.0.0 and install the new one and restart Visual Studio then it still is showing version 6.0.0 both in Web.config file and in the EntityFrameWork reference property window. I have tried to uninstall and install it various times but the result is same.

I have created just one Model and DBContext Class and apart from this whole project is empty. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

Comment: The assembly version remains 6,0,0, and the file version increases

Comment: @ErikEJ Thanks for solving me confusion. Do you have any idea why the scaffolding with EntityFramework is not working? What could be the causes and what could be the solution?

Comment: Try instaling the latest EF Tools, maybe (6,1,3)

Comment: @ErikEJ That what I have done already and got confused with the version number and posted this question. But this didn't solved the problem. I am new to EntityFramework and MVC but kindly guide me that for EntityFramework Scaffolding to work should database must exists?